# PHP - How to post relationships based on dynamic content generated with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, loops

```js
 /*On call - Add person fields dynamically*/
     var i=1;

    $("#add_row").click(function(){

        $('#addr').append("<tr class='row_"+i+"'><td>Person ID:"+i+"</td><td><input name='Person["+i+"][Name]' type='text' placeholder='Name' class='form-control input-md'  /> </td><td><input  name='Person["+i+"][Email]' type='text' placeholder='Email'  class='form-control input-md'></td><td><input  name='Person["+i+"][Mobile]' type='text' placeholder='Mobile' class='form-control input-md'></td><td><button type='button' id='"+i+"' onclick='add_vehicle(this.id);'>Add Vehicle</button></td></tr>");
        i++;
    });
 

    /*On call - Add hidden input value to section requesting to add vehicle license plate number and create plate field*/
    var vehicle = 0;
    function add_vehicle(id){

        $('<td><input type="hidden" name="Person['+id+'][hasVehicle]" value="1"></td>').appendTo('.row_'+id);

        var section = '<hr><div class"section_'+vehicle+'">Belongs To Person With ID: '+id+' <input type="text" name="Vehicle['+vehicle+'][PlateNumber]" placeholder="Plate Number" /></div><hr>';

        $(section).appendTo(".vehicle");

        vehicle++;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" action="server.php">
    <table id="tab_logic">
        <tbody>
        <tr id='addr'></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="vehicle"></div>
    <a id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Add Person </a><hr>

    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

```
<?php
     /* Posted array values*/
     $people = $_POST['Person'];
     $people_vehicle = $_POST['Vehicle'];

     //check for each person
     foreach ($people as $person) {

      //check if person has a vehicle
      if($person['hasVehicle'] == 1){

          //Owner Name:
          echo $person['Name'];

          //get all the vehicle plate numbers specified for current person
          foreach($people_vehicle as $person_vehicle) {

              //output plate numbers
              echo 
          '<pre>',print_r($person_vehicle['PlateNumber'],1),'</pre>';

          }
      }
     }
```

I have created this code that dynamically allows a "person" to add as many "plate numbers" as needed. In the backend(using PHP) I would like to capture this relationship. I wrote some PHP code that actually works when ONLY one person is added and multiple plate numbers are printed the way I want to accomplish however when I added multiple people and multiple license plates it output double the values not sure why. If someone can please assist i would appreciated.

AGAIN: The goal is to ->
A. Add as many people as needed and plate numbers dynamically and then output what plate numbers belong to who.

Results: When adding multiple people and plate numbers.

Adam Joe
E1
P1
P2
Doe John
E1
P1
P2

Results: When adding one person and multiple plate numbers.(This is what i want even when generating multiple people).

Adam Joe
P1
P2
P3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I added multiple people and multiple license plates it output double the values not sure why.

This is because you print all of the plate numbers for each person in the list. (inner loop is unnecessary)

I suggest you do this:

1. change your js so that you relate plates with one specific person (name="Vehicle['+id+'][]")

```js
var section = '<hr><div class"section_'+vehicle+'">Belongs To Person With ID: '+id+' <input type="text" name="Vehicle['+id+'][]" placeholder="Plate Number" /></div><hr>';
```

2. when printing out, use only one for loop and make use of that id index we just used

   ```
   for ($i = 1; $i <= count($people); $i++) {

     //check if person has a vehicle
     if ($people[$i]['hasVehicle'] == 1) {

       //Owner Name:
       echo $people[$i]['Name'];

       //output plate numbers
       echo
       '<pre>', print_r($people_vehicle[$i], 1), '</pre>';
     }
   }
   ```

So, you loop through all people, you get the person with number $i and check if that has a vehicle; if so, then print out list of vehicles which are also named with number $i.

The result should be like this:

```
A
Array
(
    [0] => A1
    [1] => A2
)
B
Array
(
    [0] => B1
    [1] => B2
)
C
Array
(
    [0] => C1
    [1] => C2
)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried adding 2 people where person 1 has 2 license plate number and the second person number only has one license plate number. I get the following:Mike
Array
(
    [0] => Vehicle 2
)
Ana
Array
(
    [0] => Vehicle 1
)

Comment: I have tried this. You must be missing something, please check, it works and gives this result: Mike
Array
(
    [0] => Vehicle 1
    [1] => Vehicle 2
)
Ana
Array
(
    [0] => Vehicle 3
)